# gdb python module read memory content

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb

Inside gdb to print the content at a particular memory address, I can ran the below command. It prints the content in hex

```
x <memoryaddress>

(gdb) x 299395816
0x11d86ae8: 0x0ec14153
```

I am using the gdb python module inside the gdb, what's the equivalent command to read the memory location with the gdb module inside my python script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess [inferior](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-In-Python.html#Inferiors-In-Python) is what you want:

```
(gdb) python i = gdb.inferiors()[0]
(gdb) python m = i.read_memory(0x7fffffffe39c, 4) # an int32
(gdb) python print(m.tobytes())
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```